# MBProgressHUD hide before tableView reloadData()

Tags: ios, uitableview

Here are the codes,HUD just hide very quickly. And I need 2~5s to reloadData,is there any way to accelerate or just keep the HUD appear?

```
func loadDorms() {

    var hud = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
    hud.labelText = "加载中"

    hud.showAnimated(true, whileExecutingBlock:{
        let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
        manager.GET(ServiceAPi.getRegionList(23),
            parameters: nil,
            success: {
                operation,responseObject in

                if let quote = responseObject as? NSArray {
                    self.dorms = quote
                    self.dorm  = quote[0] as! NSDictionary
                } else {
                    print("no quote")
                }
                self.leftTableView.reloadData()
                self.rightTableView.reloadData()

            }, failure: {
                operation, error in

                print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
        })

        }){
            // 移除
            hud.removeFromSuperview()
            hud = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using asynchronous call. Thus, the UI changes will take place immediately before the completion of `success` block. Thus, if you want your `MBProgressHUD` to hide after table reload, hide it in the `success` block.

```
      success: {
                operation,responseObject in

                if let quote = responseObject as? NSArray {
                    self.dorms = quote
                    self.dorm  = quote[0] as! NSDictionary
                } else {
                    print("no quote")
                }
                self.leftTableView.reloadData()
                self.rightTableView.reloadData()

               // 移除
               hud.removeFromSuperview()
               hud = nil
             }, failure: {

               // 移除
               hud.removeFromSuperview()
               hud = nil
               operation, error in

               print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `hud.removeFromSuperview()` right before `reloadData()` call inside the block. Problem is your block is executing little later than other sequential code.

> And I need 2~5s to reloadData

If you mean that `reloadData()` takes 2-5 seconds then you might want to cell your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function. `reloadData()` is almost instantaneous, given you are not doing heavy calculations in any of the datasource methods especially in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

As a side note, it is advisable to access class properties inside the block with a weak reference to self. Something like this:

```
weak var aBlockSelf = self
aBlockSelf.leftTableView.reloadData()
aBlockSelf.rightTableView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

MBProgressHUD has functionality to execute for custom time span.

See below code.

```
[MBProgressHUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(myTask) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

Create method where you can set for how much time you want to show MBProgressHUD.

```
- (void)myTask
{

    sleep(3);//set the time accordingly your need.

}
```

May be it will help you.